# How do I filter table results and grab last visible result without using SELECT?

Tags: excel, vba, select

Good Morning,

I am trying to filter a table on a separate worksheet, grab a value in the last cell visible, and copy it to the current worksheet. I can get all of this to work when manually moving between worksheets, or when selecting the worksheet in code, but I want to get the data without using select. Is there a way to get past this?

If I do not navigate to it, it grabs a value from a non filtered/non visible field. I think what I need to do is get a different statement that works without being on the page for this one:

`rngRepName.Rows(Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).Text`

Here is the Code, I appreciate any assistance!

```
Set myTable = Worksheets("Agent Chart").ListObjects("tblAgentChart")
Set rngRepID = myTable.ListColumns("REPID").DataBodyRange
Set rngRepName = myTable.ListColumns("REPNAME").DataBodyRange
Set rngSupID = myTable.ListColumns("SUPID").DataBodyRange
Set rngSupName = myTable.ListColumns("SUPNAME").DataBodyRange

intRowCount = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1

For i = 1 To intRowCount
    On Error Resume Next

    strAgentId = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    strSentStatus = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("G2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value

    If strSentStatus <> "Yes" And strSentStatus <> "No" And strSentStatus <> "Archived" Then
        'strAgentId = Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value

        If strAgentId <> "" Then 'skipping blanks
            'Turn on filter if not already turned on
            myTable.ShowAutoFilter = False
            myTable.ShowAutoFilter = True

            Set Rng = myTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("REPID", Rng.Rows(1), 0)
            SupFilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("SUPID", Rng.Rows(1), 0)

            'Filter Specific Agent
            If strAgentId <> "Support" And strAgentId <> "SUPPORT" Then
                Rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=strAgentId, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                Rng.CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Rng.Range("G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

                'Set User Name
                strAgentName = rngRepName.Rows(Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).Text
                strSupervisorName = rngSupName.Rows(Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).Text
                If strAgentName <> "" Then
                    'Agent
                    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = strAgentName
                    'Set Supervisor Name
                    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("E2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = strSupervisorName
                Else
                    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=SupFilterField, Criteria1:=strAgentId, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    'Set User Name
                    strAgentName = rngSupName.Rows(Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).Text

                    If strAgentName <> "" Then
                        'Agent
                        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = strAgentName
                        'Set Supervisor Name
                        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("E2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = ""
                    End If
                End If


            Else
                Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("E2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = "Support"
                Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = "Support"
            End If

        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0.
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Untested, but would `strAgentName = rngSupName.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).Text` work?

Comment: It did not, good thought though. I attempted to use it to select a cell for testing and it did not select anything filtered.

Comment: I have tried to reset the range like: `Set Rng = myTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and have tried to pull the value with `strAgentName = Rng.Rows(Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Text` but have not had any luck with the .SpecialCells method. Not sure what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out. It seems it was a simple as advising .SpecialCells after the table range but before specified row.

```
rngSupName.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(Range("F2").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```